# A/C Idle Issue on very hot weather

Tags: ac, mitsubishi, lancer

My Vehicle is a 1996 Mitsubishi Lancer (CB1A) with a 4G13 Engine and I'm having some A/C Issues when the weather is sunny hot. I already replace with a new ones like Mitsubishi-Air A/C Compressor, Receiver Drier, Evaporator and the Expansion Valve.

My A/C Works great on night and/or in not so hot weather but on a Hot Tropical Sunny Weather the Idle Drops Slowly and my cars shakes like forever. Does it has to do with the Compressor? the Thermostat Sensors? or the evaporator?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Did you do the work, or did a shop do the work?

Comment: @Paulster2 yup I do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The load put on your engine will come from the AirCon compressor, but that pressure is controlled by the AirCon pressure sensors. A service quality AirCon machine at your local garage will determine the fault.

Comment: My Receiver Drier has no pressure sensor and does it answer to my problem? Should I buy a Pressure Sensor?

Comment: OEM# MR201434, AirCon pressure  switch part number. If you have someone local with aparts catalogue they can show you a picture.

Comment: Thank You So much that Part No# Really Helps. I already added it to my Receiver Drier and its now working fine ;)